# When I am root, "mysql" connects without a password, even though I've set one

Tags: mysql, password

When I am root, "mysql" connects without a password, even though I've set one:

```
# mysqladmin -u root password 'whatever'
# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: (typing the 'whatever' above)
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4 to server version: 4.1.22-standard

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> Bye
```

but unfortunately this also happens...

```
# mysql -u root 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 25 to server version: 4.1.22-standard

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql>
```

So even though I've set the password, and it IS checked when I use "-p",
it is however not necessary!?!?

**EDIT**: It was my .my.cnf, it had the login password inside it. 
Removed it, all OK.

Comment: Add your "Edit" as answer please.

Comment: Cross-post: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/15130/6597

Comment: Do you have "skip-grant-tables" enabled in your my.cnf file?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have user credentials in your ~/.my.cnf

```
[client]
user=john
password=smith
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that the MySQL root user was using the [Socket Peer-Credential Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html).

From what I understand, is that if the unix user that invokes the `mysql` command matches the MySQL user it will allow a connection for a local socket (no remote). So passing in any password will have no effect because this type of auth does not need a password.

You can see if you have any users that use `auth_socket` plugin.

`select Host, User, plugin from mysql.user where plugin = 'auth_socket';`

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 and ran the `mysql_secure_installation` script.

Answer (score -2):

```
mysql> update user set plugin='' where User='root'; 
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would improve your answer